# Evaluating a limit ......

Tags: integration, limits

Let $E_{r}$={$x=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}){\in}R^{3}$ : $\left \|x\right \|{\geq}r$} 
Evaluate
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \varepsilon ^{9} \int_{E_{\varepsilon}} \left \| x \right \|^{-12} (\cos x_{1})  dx$$

Comment: Is $r=\varepsilon$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin sorry for a typo